# AWS Lambda function URL AWS_IAM signature version 4 calculate to Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created Lambda function URL with auth type as AWS_IAM
I tried to call the API using fetch in javascript.
However, a 403 Forbidden error occurred and this message was printed.

```
message: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
```

This is the code I calculate signature version 4 and call the API.
I think the method of calculating the signature is wrong. Please tell me how to calculate the signature with javascript.

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
  var kDate = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
  var kRegion = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
  var kService = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
  var kSigning = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

  return kSigning;
}

const now = new Date();
const amzdate = now
  .toJSON()
  .replace(/[-:]/g, "")
  .replace(/\.[0-9]*/, "");
const datestamp = now.toJSON().replace(/-/g, "").replace(/T.*/, "");

const accessKey = "";
const secretKey = "";

const region = "ap-northeast-2";
const serviceName = "lambda";

const apiMethod = "GET";
const apiHost =
  "https://{lambda function id}.lambda-url.ap-northeast-2.on.aws/";
const apiQueryString = "";
const canonicalHeaders = "host:" + apiHost + "\nx-amz-date:" + amzdate + "\n";
const signedHeaders = "host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token";
const payloadHash = CryptoJS.SHA256("").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
const canonicalRequest =
  apiMethod +
  "\n" +
  apiQueryString +
  "\n" +
  canonicalHeaders +
  "\n" +
  signedHeaders +
  "\n" +
  payloadHash;

const algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
const credentialScope =
  datestamp + "/" + region + "/" + serviceName + "/" + "aws4_request";

const stringToSign =
  algorithm +
  "\n" +
  amzdate +
  "\n" +
  credentialScope +
  "\n" +
  CryptoJS.SHA256(canonicalRequest).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

const signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, datestamp, region, serviceName);
const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signingKey, stringToSign).toString(
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex
);

const authorizationHeader =
  algorithm +
  " Credential=" +
  accessKey +
  "/" +
  credentialScope +
  ", SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=" +
  signature;

fetch(URL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-Amz-Date": amzdate,
      Authorization: authorizationHeader,
    },
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function (data) {
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reimplement the whole signature logic on your own as that is very error prone. AWS SDK JS v3 has a dedicated module for that and there is a great blog post that explains how to use it for signing requests: https://dev.to/aws-builders/signing-requests-with-aws-sdk-in-lambda-functions-476

Answer (score 0):

Your `signedHeaders` contains `x-amz-security-token` which you are not adding to the canonical headers.
Also in your `authorizationHeader` your're setting `SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date` which does not have `x-amz-security-token`.

Try removing `;x-amz-security-token` from `signedHeaders` string.